# C# Siteminder Authentication

Tags: c#, siteminder

I am trying to write some code to connect to an HTTPS site that uses Siteminder authentication.

I keep getting a 401.  Any ideas?

I have read a few different things on here but none have really seemed all that helpful.  I am also using Fiddler/Firefox Tamper to snoop what's going on.

Here is what I've got so far in regards to code:

```
try
        {

            Uri uri = new Uri("https://websiteaddresshere");
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

            request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";

            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
        //    request.Connection = "Keep-Alive";
           // request.Method = "Get";
           // request.Accept = "text";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            Cookie emersoncookie = new Cookie("SMCHALLENGE",  "YES");
            emersoncookie.Domain = "mydomain";
            emersoncookie.Path = "/";




           // authentication
            var cache = new CredentialCache();
            cache.Add(uri, "False", new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword"));

            request.Credentials = cache;


            // response.
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
                    MessageBox.Show(stream.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            string responseText;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(responseText.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more reading on the MSDN website I decided to go a different route.

I ended up making this a service since it will need to be a service at the end of the day and did the following:

```
 CookieContainer emersoncookie = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("https://websiteaddress");

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            request.CookieContainer = emersoncookie;

            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();

            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\\somefolder\\somefile.someextention"))
            using (Stream input = resStream)
            {
                input.CopyTo(output);
            }
```

To anyone that might be running into Siteminder authentication issues, this piece of code works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Jasen's code to work. Maybe your SM setup is different from mine. But with SiteMinder it's generally a two step authentication process. The code block below works for me:

```
        //Make initial request
        RestClient client = new RestClient("http://theResourceDomain/myApp");
        client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        IRestResponse response = client.Get(new RestRequest("someProduct/orders"));

        //Now add credentials.
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");
        //Get resource from the SiteMinder URI which will redirect to the correct API URI upon authentication.
        response = client.Get(new RestRequest(response.ResponseUri));
```

Although this uses RestSharp, it can be easily replicated using **HttpClient** or even **HttpWebRequest**.